# How to retrieve full transaction details for all transactions between two dates using Authorize.net API?

Tags: authorize.net

I am attempting to retrieve a list of all transactions between a start and end date with Authorize.net API. I need detailed reports for each transaction such as total sale, tax, address, zip, etc. for tax reports by region. Typically, I do this without an API by selecting “Search for a Transaction” on the Authorize.net main page, selecting the start and end dates, and filtering for transactions “Settled Successfully”. I then download a text file of all these transactions (takes a few minutes for 20K or so transactions) and process from this point locally.

I would like to use an API for this, however in the documentation Authorize.net does not have a function that quite captures what I need. “Get Settled Batch List” retrieves a batch list of all transactions between two dates, but does not give detailed reports for each item, only summaries. On the other hand, “Get Transaction Details” yields detailed reports, but only for a single transaction specified by transaction ID. I do not have the IDs, but even if I did, I would prefer to somehow retrieve in bulk from a single call instead of 20K calls which will slow the process down way too much. Basically, what I am hoping for is a mix between these two functions.

Does anyone know of a potential solution to this? Or am I missing a helpful feature? I am using C# if that is significant. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can't get details in bulk. You will need to get a summary and then make individual API calls to the details.

Comment: @JohnConde "Get Settled Batch List" has a batchID attribute but not transID. can I get transID somehow?